# Postgres: script updates to pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql

I am in the process of creating deployment scripts for a web application. The script should run on a fresh node (e.g. ec2 from Amazon) and install and configure my dependencies. When it comes to postgresql the script looks like:

```
apt-get install postgresql
createuser $db_user
createdb $db_name --owner=$db_user
....
```

This works - but I wondered if it was possible to configure access to the database (i.e. add/update a record to the `pg_hba.conf` file) in similar manner? Or do I have to resort to real low level string manipulations to achieve this from a script?

Comment: Not certain, but I don't think postgres tools modify pg_hba.conf.